# Suitelink Reference Table

Tags: wonderware

I work with Wonderware software. One of the objects used to perform communication between Wonderware and the PLC is called Suitelink. In it, I have a table defined that has the name of one of my application fields on the left side and the name of the PLC tag providing its value on the right.

Once this saved and activated (deployed) the PLC tags will feed values in the field attributes to Wonderware.

Does anyone know where is this list saved in the system?

I am working at a web page and want to retrieve this list dynamically so I can have the page updated based on the current live value of the PLC tag being used.

I have looked in the database but could not find it.

Comment: So to summarize, in the end you want to show the live values on a web page?

Comment: Yes that is correct and no I can't allow general publicaccess to the ObjectViewer

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\ProgramData\Wonderware\DAServer
```

Then within there you'll have several subfolders for your DA Servers. Open the subfolder to find a `*.AAcfg` file and your contents are in there in what looks like an XML format. You'll be hunting for all the `<DeviceItem>` tags

Comment: I think he wants the live values instead of the configured list.

Comment: I thought otherwise from the last sentence of his first paragraph. I'd assume the live values are fed *to* the DAServer by Wonderware based on the tag definitions in the program. Its easy to parse in a published app, but difficult if a deployed System Platform app where I assume they're held in the Galaxy Database?

Comment: I have looked at the Galaxy database but haven't found this yet.  What I found is that for each topic in a SuiteLink object, there is a ScanGroupList attribute who contains the list of topics and for each Topic there is an attribute named AliasDatabase containing a Xml definition of the attributes and correspondent tags.
So I defined a page and in the page set a few labels and as name of the label I gave the name of the Field Attribute and as tooltip the name of the tag.

Comment: Now I look at 2 problems:
1 - How to dynamically change the name of the PLC Tag (aka assign the tooltip based on what the table in suitelink indicated)
2 - How to assign the text attribute to this label based on a value returned by a dll dispatching me to a handler method
ANyone has ever done anything of this type?

Comment: so let's say the lbl01.Text is "" and the DLL returns 5 I want the text of the label to become "5" and then post the change